# Upload a file in ASP.NET Core using only the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to identify a solution on how to upload a file using only the controller out of the model and save it to the server.

I'm using the following code to get the path of the file that I'm trying to upload but the value of the "filepath" is always null as it can be seen in the screenshot attached

```
[Route("/test1/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadGem(string filePath, string filename)
{
    filePath = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    return Ok();
    // Save the file to the server
}
```

[image]

So my question is,how can i get either the filename or the path from the insomnia request?

Answer (score 1):

The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-small-files-with-buffered-model-binding-to-physical-storage) already provides us with a sample for uploading file.

We should use `IFormFile` in the Controller to receive the file and get the fileName and path through `IFormFile`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size });
}
```

It's also suitable for the scenario that you want to have a controller API.

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public IActionResult upload([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] string fileName) {
     return Ok();
}
```

[image]

If you want to define the file path separately, then you could also define it in the controller action.